# .Net working directory, paths, and imported html

Tags: .net

I've received some html with Javascript from an external company that needs integrating with our .Net project.

I have taken the approach of copying the html directly into a user control as the html changes infrequently. This caused an issue with the scripts as they refer to paths such as img/myimage.jpg and the working directory has changed as the page is part of our SiteCore system. I have updated the images to use relative paths from the root directory e.g. /resources/img/myimage.jpg and this gets it mostly working.

This should work functionally but it doesn't function as expected and I cant identify the issue (no 404 issues).

So Im thinking about alternatives:
How can I import the html with the  working directory of the html maintained so the scripts continuing to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"So Im thinking about alternatives: How can I import the html with the working directory of the html maintained so the scripts continuing to work?"

I don't know of anyway to do that simply.

"This should work functionally but it doesn't function as expected and I cant identify the issue (no 404 issues)."

I think you should try to solve this, your original tack of using a usercontrol was a good one IMO.  Maybe the problem isn't 404 (did you use F12 to check?) but instead is a script clash (with one of your existing scripts)?